# Create EPUB3 Reader App in Python

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, epub, epub3, ebook-reader

I am trying to create EPUB3 reader application in python for that I explored some python libraries like:

```
                i) Epubzilla
                ii) EbookLib
                iii) pyepub
                iv) epub 0.5.1
```

but I did't got perfect python API to render EPUB3 files. 
So I was thinking to use '*zipfile*' will extract the containts of EPUB3 and will display accordingly but I don't want to extract EPUB3 file manually and display html,media file.

So please any one can suggest me that,

1) which way I need to follow to create EPUB3 reader application in python?

2) Is there any python library will give direct access of Epub3 file?

Comment: All the libraries you listed (hey, there is also yael, written by me) allows you to parse metadata, spine and ToC of EPUB files. After that, you need to get the XHTML (and maybe other assets like CSS or images), and display it in a browser. There is no "display EPUB" library out there, because that is basically is an "HTML rendering engine". What you probably want to do consists in writing a PyQt or Tinker app, wrapping an HTML renderer where you feed the HTML files of the EPUB, plus some chrome to control navigation, show the ToC, etc.

Comment: Hi Alberto, thanks for reply, I create a web based and standalone app prototype for the EPUB reader, but facing issue that got book data as per toc but how to render the media file of epub3 like video and audio? and about DRM policies, these API are failed to read DRMed EPUB files.

Comment: This seems a different question now. Better opening a new one, then. Anyway, for A/V resources: extract the A/V files and use ``<audio>`` or ``<video>`` elements to show them. For DRM (assuming you talk about Adobe DRM): you need to purchase an ACS license from Adobe, or drop the support for DRM-ed files.